# What does Will do?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Does this reduce the damage your soldier takes when hit? I can't find Will on the XCOM Wiki. There is a skill called Will to survive and this is what it does: "Reduces normal damage taken by 2 if in cover and not flanked."

Comment: Or does it make your soldiers panick less often?

Comment: Highly related:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103283/2578

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Will** is combination of 3 stats from classic game: [Morale](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Morale) , [Psionic Strength](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Psionic_Strength) and [Psionic Skill](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Psionic_Skill).

Advantages of higher *Will* stats:

- less chance of panicking
- higher chance to be psi gifted
- less susceptible to alien psi attacks
- more effective in their own psi skills

*Will to survive* skill is unrelated to *Will* stat.

Comment: are you sure your own will makes your psi attacks more likely to hit?  If thats the case, I wonder if using a smoke grenade with the will buff, a psychic will buff skill, and a stim would make my psychic a super psychic that can even mind control ethereals and sectoid commanders.

Comment: @yx: AFAIK, the chances of attack success are dependent on difference between your will and opponent's will; and yes, apparently using smoke buff is standard tactic (haven't tried it yet)

Comment: neat (12 chars)